# Fastest way of finding the index of the closest element in a non-sorted Python list of floats

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given as input a list of floats that is not sorted, what would be the most efficient way of finding the index of the closest element to a certain value? Some potential solutions come to mind:

**For:**

```
x = random.sample([float(i) for i in range(1000000)], 1000000)
```

**1) Own function:**

```
def min_val(lst, val):
    min_i = None
    min_dist = 1000000.0
    for i, v in enumerate(lst):
        d = abs(v - val)
        if d < min_dist:
            min_dist = d
            min_i = i
    return min_i
```

Result:

```
%timeit min_val(x, 5000.56)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
```

**2) Min**

```
%timeit min(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: abs(x[i]-5000.56))
100 loops, best of 3: 16.8 ms per loop
```

**3) Numpy (including conversion)**

```
%timeit np.abs(np.array(x)-5000.56).argmin()
100 loops, best of 3: 3.88 ms per loop
```

From that test, it seems that converting the list to numpy array is the best solution. However two questions come to mind:

1. Was that indeed a realistic comparison?
2. Is the numpy solution the fastest way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Python loops are slow, and numpy operates at C speed. The larger your array is the bigger speedup will the numpy implementation get over the raw python. You can always write a Cython function (or C function with Python wrappers) to do this directly with one loop over the array (since the numpy implementation loops 3 times: substraction, abs and argmin). But with available libraries I think numpy is the fastest one.

Comment: You can get a small additional speedup by using `((x - 5000.56)**2).argmin()` instead of `abs`.

Comment: I don't see any noticeable difference in %timeit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the [partition algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm) from QuickSort. The partition algorithm rearranges a list such that the pivot element is in its final location after invocation. Based on the value of the pivot, you could then partition the portion of the array that is likely to contain the element closest to your target. Once you've either found the element you're after or a have a partition of length 1 that contains your element you're done.

The general problem you're addressing is a [selection problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).

In your question you were wondering about what sort of array/list implementation to use, and that will have an impact on performance. A bigger factor will be the search algorithm as opposed to the list/array representation.

*Edit in light of comment from @Andrzej*

Ah, then I misunderstood your question. Strictly speaking, linear search is  always O(n), so efficiency within the bounds of Big-Oh analysis is the same regardless of underlying data structure. The gotcha here is that for linear search you want a nice simple data structure to make the run-time performance as good as possible.

A Python list is an array of references to objects while (to my understanding) a Numpy array is a contiguous array of objects. The Numpy array will perform better since it doesn't have to dereference the objects to get to the values.

Your comparison technique seems reasonable for Python list vs. Numpy array. I'd be reluctant to say that a Numpy array is the fastest way to solve the problem, but it should perform better than a Python list.

Comment: My question was about an unsorted array in which case there does not seem to be any benefit of applying a better algorithm than a linear search. Unless: 1) the search will be repeated multiple times, 2) there exists some pattern in the data. Excluding those two situations, it boils down to doing the most efficient linear search doesn't it?

Comment: The difference between contiguous array and references makes sense. Thanks!